# Manipulating lines of code through string variables

Tags: string, vba

Is it possible to write lines of code using string variables?

For instance instead of writing:

```
If rs.Fields(1).Value > 1 And rs.Fields(2).Value = "B" Then
    Msgbox "A"
End If
```

Writing:

```
strA = "rs.Fields(1).Value > 1 And rs.Fields(2).Value = " & """B"""
If strA Then
    Msgbox "A"
End If
```

Comment: You can use **EVal()**. You might need to concatenate dynamic values though. So in other words, it is exactly the same as using the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed on using EVal() as per PaulFrancis' suggestion